# Marginal probability distribution of unit circle random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am given a task stating that there is a bivariate random vector X such that:
$$\begin{equation}
  p_x(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \frac1\pi, & \text{if}\ x^2+y^2 < 1 \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}  $$
and I am asked to find margianl distribution with respect to X and Y.
I tried to catch it up by google and found some answers. e.g.
$$f(x)_x=\int_\sqrt{1^2-x^2}^\sqrt{1^2+x^2}\frac1\pi dy$$
One thing I am interested in. Where the integration bounds came from. Can anyone explain pls?

Comment: I find different limits: $- \sqrt(1-x^2)$ and $\sqrt(1-x^2)$

Comment: Thanks, just realized that I can do in such way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the domain $\mathcal{D} = \{(x_1,x2) \vert x_1^2 + x_2^2 <1\}$. Given a fix $x_1$, if $(x_1, x_2)$ belongs to $\mathcal{D}$, $x_2$ has to satisfy $ - \sqrt{1-x_1^2}< x_2 < \sqrt{1-x_1^2}$, where we are taken positive roots:

\begin{equation}
  f_{X_1}(x_1) = \int_{D} f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) d x_2 = \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \int_{- \sqrt{1-x_1^2}}^{ \sqrt{1-x_1^2}} \frac{1}{\pi} d x_2 = \frac{2\sqrt{1-x_1^2}}{\pi}  & \text{if}\ x_1^2 < 1 \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: How to find the marginal distribution then for x_2? If I integrate over -1, 1 I end up with a constant of 2/pi which cannot be right?

Comment: Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are symmetric, you should get the same expression for both cases